# FreeBSD - How can I let server A get web access via server B over a specific port?

Tags: proxy, freebsd, pf

**Setup:**

- Server A: FreeBSD 10 - IP: 100.100.100.100
- Server B: FreeBSD 9  - IP: 200.200.200.200

Both servers use pf.conf.

**Desired result:**

I want server A to be able to get web access (port 80) via server B over a specific port (ex: 3333). How would one accomplish that in the easiest possible way? Is it possible to do this by just changing pf.conf on server B?

Any hands on examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need any more information?

Comment: Your sample IP numbers don't give any hint about network configuration. Are they on the same subnet, is one routing for the other or is there a router.

Comment: And Don't ask the same question twice. http://superuser.com/questions/783171/freebsd-how-can-i-let-server-a-get-web-access-via-server-b-over-a-specific-por